# How to Use Google Fitness Api to build sample Step Counter?

Tags: java, android, api, google-fit

Today, I was starting to deal with google fitness API to complete my smartwatch application that record heart rates and send data to cloud to do some processing on this data but if I want to go with traditional way to program PPG heart rate sensor it will be difficult to do signal Processing on PPG signal because that I switched from traditional way to program sensor to use Google API because it has everything I need from it. However, When I started to learn how to use Google Fitness API from api website, I didn't understand how to Use Google Api because I felt examples that given from api website was not clear to me because there is many deprecated methods from google and new methods revel. Therefore, I want now to program sample step counter by using Google Fitness api as first stage to understanding how to use this api until I reach heart rate sensor, and now I already connected google fitness api with android studio and what is next step to program sample step counter application.

In general, I have some Ideas how build this application but in coding part I don't know how to program by api methods.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: code that provide from google fitness api website like this https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started but I didn't understand code structure and if you ask about traditional way by access hardware.Sensor and SensorEvent ... etc